# What does func (N) means in man pages?

Tags: linux

For example , in page http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/bpf.2.html

What does the (2) mean in bpf(2) ?

Comment: That's the man page section, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man_page#Manual_sections . Section 2 is usually for system calls.

Comment: In some cases there are distinct man pages with same name in different sections, such as printf(1) and printf(3) and readdir(2) and readdir(3).